# Can't access custom jars from tomcat's lib folder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, classpath

I have two custom jars(websso jars) which are required by multiple projects. Therefore, I put those jars inside Tomcat's lib folder. But, those custom jars use springframework security(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class) jars. When I deploy the application, it gives me following exceptions.

How can I access the custom jars deployed in tomcat's lib folder from the application?

```
 Related cause:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error
 loading class
 [com.db.websso.providers.authentication.springsecurity.WebSSOPreAuthenticationFilter]
 for bean with name 'preAuthenticationProcessingFilter' defined in
 ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/root-context.xml]: problem with
 class file or dependent class; nested exception is
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
```

How can I access the custom jars deployed in tomcat's lib folder from the application?

Comment: For starters, cut your stacktrace to relevant error and post around 20 lines extra. Secondly, format your code by selecting the text and press ctrl+k. Third, you should also explain which JAR's are those, and how they are dependent on Spring-Security. Fourth, without understanding your dependencies, how can one decide, so post your POM.xml. Here is link on how to put code in posts on SO : how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which version of Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the Spring JARs into the `server/lib/` folder as well. Specifically: All dependencies of JARs outside of `WEB-INF/lib/` must be in the `server/lib/` folder. Why?

Your web app is loaded with the WebAppClassLoader which has some tricks in its sleeve to make loading JARs from `WEB-INF/lib/` possible. For any class which it can't find, it will ask the parent classloader. The parent, which has been created way before the WebAppClassLoader , has no idea of web apps and `WEB-INF/lib/`.

A simple reasons is this: If you have two apps deployed which contain Spring JARs, which one should the parent class loader prefer?

The means you web app loads the security code. Those classes can only see what's in `server/lib/` and **nothing else**.

That's why I avoid `server/lib/` - it doesn't help much and it can create a lot of problems (like `ClassCastException: foo.Bar != foo.Bar`). Because a lot of Java code doesn't get it's globals right, either, I aim for a single app per server. Yes, I know about the outcry after such an obviously stupid and unprofessional statement. It's just that this approach always works, reduces maintenance cost, and when it doesn't work, you have only a few specific places to look - instead of a few hundred megabytes of alien code.

Comment: Is it not possible to load my application WEB-INF/lib jars first and then the tomcat's lib jars?

I have to use `websso.jar` which just contain a PRE-AUTH-FILTER custom filter. And this jar refers to spring-security-web.jar. This `websso.jar` has been placed inside tomcat lib folder as it is used by some other application.

My application uses that filter from `spring-context.xml` file and I have got all the required lib e.g spring and other jar inside my application's WEB-INF lib folder. When I deploy this application it gives me ClassNotFoundException for that Filter class.

Comment: Do you have any comments on this? How can make this work?

Comment: You have to put `websso.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib/`